# Razer thunderbolt 4 dock works with Linux but not Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, displayport, usb-c, docking-station, thunderbolt

### Problem

Hello all, I am having a problem with my Windows 11 and a Razer Thunderbolt 4 Dock, specifically, I cannot get video (display port over USB-C) output from my dock to my monitor. Windows also cannot detect the display when connected via the dock but will work if I connect the display directly to my laptop via USB-C cable. The dock works perfectly with Linux (arch, Nvidia binary driver installed), which makes me think this could be a Windows issue, unfortunately I my Windows foo is not amazing.

So some background, I am a lifetime Linux user and developer, and only boot into Windows 11 (dual boot setup) to play games. My dock was working with both Linux and Windows, however, after shutting down one day, my setup no longer works when I boot into Windows.

My Windows install is incredibly minimal and I do not tweak system settings. I pretty much have drivers and steam games installed.

After reading the further details below, please let me know if you think there is anything further I can try.

### Hardware Details

**Dock:** Razer Thunderbolt 4 Dock Chroma

**Laptop:** Inspiron 16 Plus ([link to exact build](https://www.dell.com/en-nz/shop/laptop-notebook-computers/inspiron-16-plus/spd/inspiron-16-7620-laptop/hni762002nz))
This laptop has dual Nvidia and Intel graphics cards, with the thunderbolt port being wired directly to the Nvidia card

**Monitor:** MSI Optix MAG342CQR 34" Ultrawide Gaming Monitor

**Graphic Driver:** Nvidia gaming driver (not studio)

**Hardware configuration:** Laptop thunderbolt out -> Dock thunderbolt in -> Dock USB-C out -> Display port in on monitor

### What I Have Tried

Reinstalling graphics driver

Reinstalling all other drivers provided by the laptop manufacturer

Reset any custom bios config

Replace all cables

Try laptop with other docks, all work with Linux but not Windows

Try other screens, all work with Linux but not Windows

### Potential Further Steps

Reinstall Windows 11

Replace dock (not convinced this is a dock issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the exact same issue with a similarly configured Razer Blade 15 (mid 2021) and Razer Thunderbolt 4 Dock Chroma on Windows 11.

The only workaround I have found was to downgrade Nvidia drivers to the ancient 512.95 (30.0.15.1295) version from May 2022.

Any newer driver doesn't work for me despite release notes repeatedly claiming it was fixed.

Comment: I will give this a try later today and see if it works. A little surprised the Windows driver seems to be experiencing fewer issues than the Linux equivalent, who would have thought?

Comment: Worked immediately.  Many thanks, my friend!